# MS Access ImportXML "DTD not allowed"

Tags: xml, ms-access, dtd, dtd-parsing

I'm trying to import an XML file into Access, but I get the

> 31593 error: DTD not allowed.

I understand that there are some lines in my xml that cause the fail, I test deleting those lines from my file and it works fine, but I need to know how to delete those lines in my VBA script because I download that xml and I don't want to delete those lines each time I import the files. I was trying t find out how to do this, maybe you can give me some idea about how to do it.

Comment: So are you looking for a way to pre-process the XML file to remove the `<!DOCTYPE` element (or similar)? If so, that would suggest [opening it as a text file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method), reading it line-by-line, and writing the lines to an output file while skipping the lines(s) that you want to omit.

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I just finishing to est and it works perfectly, thanks